# messageArrived never called in mqtt paho client

Tags: java, mqtt, paho

I have a program running using mqtt paho version **MqttConnectOptions.MQTT_VERSION_3_1_1** . I subscribe to topic "device/+/publish" and message from hardware is received at my program. Till yesterday it was running good, today I got an issue that code was not proceeding after the subscribe line. I changed my mqttclient object to MqttAsyncClient. and subscribe code as

```
mqttClient.subscribe("device/+/publish", 0 , new IMqttMessageListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        System.out.println(
                                "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

                        processMessage(mqttMessage, collarTopic, identity);
                    }
                });
```

messageArrived is also written in MqttCallbackExtended() like

```
mqttClient.setCallback(new MqttCallbackExtended() {
        @Override
        public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            System.out.println(
                    "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            processMessage(mqttMessage, collarTopic, identity);

        }
```

But this is never called in my program. I can see the message received with same subscription in MQTTBox but not in my program.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried subscribing with a QoS of 1 or 2? 0 makes no guarantees that you will ever receive a message.

Comment: ` String collarTopic = topic.replace("/publish", "");` what is sense of this replace?

Comment: @JacekCz  that is some internal logic.  it has nothign to do with messgeArrived

Comment: sorry friend, this han't too much sense. Above string.toString() seems chaotic copy & paste. My trust in whole code is very, very low

Comment: are You sure syntax in first line? Chaos, chaos, chaos